# Even and Odd row fetching using sql query

Tags: sql

Input Table :

```
page_no title
1   scrambled egg
2   Fondue
3   Sandwich
4   Tomato Soup
6   Liver
```

Required Query Result :

```
leftcolumn rightcolumn
null       scrambled egg
fondue     sandwich
tomato     null
liver      null
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Add (13, bacon) to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select max(case when page_no % 2 = 0 then title end) as leftcolumn,
       max(case when page_no % 2 = 1 then title end) as rightcolumn      
from t
group by floor( page_no / 2);
```

The `%` is the modulo function.  Some databases use `MOD()` instead.